# Статическая библиотека: убрать зависимость от внутренних библиотек

Tags: c++, lib, visual-studio

Есть самописная библиотека С++ (.h и .cpp соответственно) использующая библиотеки OpenCV и boost. 
Заголовочный файл имеет вид:

```
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
и дальше объявления классов и функций (реализованных в cpp)
```

Использую VS2010, если к проекту "напрямую" подкючать эту библиотеку, прописывать все необходимые файлы для работы openCV и boost, то все работает.
Пробовал собрать статическую библиотеку lib. Подключаю заголовочный файл подключаю lib файл к новому проекту и компилятор ругается на неизвестные ему библиотеки:  cv.h и тп...

Как можно создать статическую библиотеку, так что бы человеку которому необходимо написать прогу с использованием самописной библиотеки, не надо было иметь собранные OpenCV и boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `boost::ublas` — это `header-only library`, поэтому к вопросу она отношения не имеет. То есть тому, кто захочет использовать вашу штуковину, нужно будет иметь хэдеры `boost'a`, и в этом никакой проблемы лично я не вижу.
- Далее, правильное решение с `OpenCV` следующее — **не нужно** `embedd'ить` весь `OpenCV` в вашу библиотеку, а нужно поставлять библиотеку `as is,` а всех пользователей вашей библиотеки отправлять на [`opencv.org`](http://opencv.org)

> - Решение с `embedd'ингом` плохое, поскольку вы лишаете пользователей вашей библиотеки возможности динамически линковаться с `OpenCV` и форсируете *увеличение размера* любого приложения, собранного с применением вашей библиотеки.
> - Также `embedd'инг` всего `OpenCV` в вашу библиотеку чреват *проблемами с безопасностью.* Что должен сделать пользователь вашей библиотеки, в которую статически влинкован `OpenCV 2.4.5`, если он узнает, что в `2.4.5` нашли `exploit,` который позволяет получить доступ к любой системе? `OpenCV,` скажем, выпускает для этого патч-релиз `2.4.6,` а ваш пользователь кусает локти.
> - Последний пример, разумеется, сильно притянут за уши, но аргумент вполне себе имеет место быть.

- Если вы все-таки решите статически `embedd'ить` `OpenCV` в вашу библиотеку, то в `Visual Studio` это можно сделать, например, с помощью [приложения `LIB.`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7ykb2k5f)

> Вам нужно взять файл вашей библиотеки и файл статически собранной библиотеки `OpenCV,` сдампить из них `obj` файлы и склеить эти файлы в новую библиотеку, которую и отправлять пользователю.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток! 
На мой взгляд тут два варианта:
1) Собираем библиотеку и компонуем ее со сторонними библиотеками **статически**, но нашу библиотеку делаем компонуемой **динамически** + пишем к ней интерфейс убрав все упоминания о заголовочных файлах boost и OpenCV. Пользователю предоставляем нашу библиотеку + наши заголовочные файлы.

2)Собираем библиотеку и компонуем ее со сторонними библиотеками **статически**, и нашу библиотеку также делаем статической. Затем пользователю Вам необходимо будет предоставить Вашу либу + все заголовки (как Вашей библиотеки, так и сторонних).

Других способов нет - по крайней мере они мне не известны